# Javascript Footer Callback Sum Values in one column for each unique combined value in 2 other columns

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a report of company dividend Payments on different dates which repeat the Value of the Share Holding for every payment.

Each unique Portfolio.Symbol may have multiple payments, but will only have one Value repeated for each Payment.

I need to SUM the Values in the Value Column for each unique Portfolio.Symbol combination.

```
Date        Portfolio  Symbol   Value  Payment.   Sum Value
2020-11-27  DEA        GSK      26000  30.        26000
2020-11-30  ISA        GSK      44000  30.        44000
2021-06-30  ISA        GSK      44000  30.        0, repeat of ISA.GSK so ignore
2021-06-30  DEA        GSK      26000  30.        0, repeat of DEA.GSK so ignore

Unique Sum                      70000   
So in the above example Sum of Value should be Sum of last column 
26000+44000=70000
```

I have set up a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cpshart/s478gvcj/53/

as a starting point using the datatables.net footer callback

If anyone can help me in getting a solution it would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you provide in jsfiddle, it looks like you haven't added a condition to only add unique data. Then as a solution you can try using the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "footerCallback": function(row, data, start) {
      var api = this.api();

      var intVal = function(i) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ?
          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
          typeof i === 'number' ?
          i : 0;
      };

      var indexOfPortofolio = 1;
      var indexOfSymbol = 2;
      var indexOfValue = 3;

      // Total over all pages
      var total = api
        .rows()
        .data()
        .toArray()
        .reduce(function(a, v, i) {
          var uniquePortofolioSymbol = v[indexOfPortofolio] + v[indexOfSymbol];
          if (a.uniqueList.indexOf(uniquePortofolioSymbol) === -1) {
            a.sum += intVal(v[indexOfValue]);
            a.uniqueList.push(uniquePortofolioSymbol);
            a.uniqueIndex.push(i);
          }
          return a;
        }, { sum: 0, uniqueList: [], uniqueIndex: [] });

      // Total over this page
      var pageTotal = api
        .rows({ page: 'current' })
        .data()
        .toArray()
        .reduce(function(a, v, i) {
          var uniquePortofolioSymbol = v[indexOfPortofolio] + v[indexOfSymbol];
          if (
            a.uniqueList.indexOf(uniquePortofolioSymbol) === -1
            && total.uniqueIndex.indexOf(start + i) !== -1
          ) {
            a.sum += intVal(v[indexOfValue]);
            a.uniqueList.push(uniquePortofolioSymbol);
          }
          return a;
        }, { sum: 0, uniqueList: [] });

      // Update footer
      $(api.column(3).footer()).html(
        pageTotal.sum + ' ( ' + total.sum + ' )'
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Portfolio</th>
      <th>Symbol</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Payment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2020-11-30</td>
      <td>ISA</td>
      <td>RLSEB</td>
      <td>30000</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-06-30</td>
      <td>ISA</td>
      <td>GSK</td>
      <td>44000</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2020-11-30</td>
      <td>ISA</td>
      <td>GSK</td>
      <td>44000</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2020-11-27</td>
      <td>DEA</td>
      <td>GSK</td>
      <td>26000</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-02-30</td>
      <td>ISA</td>
      <td>RLSEB</td>
      <td>30000</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-05-30</td>
      <td>ISA</td>
      <td>RLSEB</td>
      <td>30000</td>
      <td>54</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-05-30</td>
      <td>ISA</td>
      <td>RLSEB</td>
      <td>30000</td>
      <td>57</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-05-30</td>
      <td>DEA</td>
      <td>RLSEB</td>
      <td>20000</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-05-30</td>
      <td>DEA</td>
      <td>RLSEB</td>
      <td>20000</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-05-30</td>
      <td>ISA</td>
      <td>RLSEB</td>
      <td>30000</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-05-30</td>
      <td>DEA</td>
      <td>RLSEB</td>
      <td>20000</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Yusut T, many thanks for solving my problem great news!!, I thought it best to provide a starting point of code rather than my failed attempts at solving the problem in the jsfiddle, I hope that is ok ?. Many Thanks Colin